# Access sql statements from a dataset based on table name

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

SQL server stored procedure having multiple select statements

```
Create procedure mySP
as
begin

 select column1,column2,column3 from table1;
 select column4,column5,column6 from table2;
 select column7,column8,column9 from table3;

end

DataSet ds=GetDataFromSQLProcedure();

ds.Tables[0] - datatable will hold the data from table1.
ds.Tables[1] - datatable will hold the data from table2.
ds.Tables[2] - datatable will hold the data from table3.
```

How do I get/assign/retrieve datatables based on name instead of number (so that even when the order of select statements change in stored procedure, I don't need to change my C# code)?

I.E.

```
ds.Tables["table1"] instead of ds.Tables[0]?
```

Comment: There's no way to know that the first record set returned by the SP came from table1.  What if the first record set returned happened to be table1 joined to table2?  What would the table name be then?

Comment: You can't have sql change the name of your tables, notice the names are just generically assigned. ds.Tables[0].TableName You can from dotnet check the column names, maybe that will get you what you need.

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us - I am looking for an option to use a name (in my example, it happened to be table1, however, when you join more tables, is there any way to retrieve data based on names instead of number?)

Comment: You could insert a fake first column named after the table and then when you check the data, check the first column and then use that to split your data correctly?